# AJAX returning data from an older AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that is populated by dynamically loading data through AJAX calls.

Main page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#searchbar" ).load( "searchbar.php" );
});
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loader" ).show();
});
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( "#loader" ).hide();
});
```

searchbar.php:

```
$( "#search" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = encodeURIComponent($( "#name" ).val());
  var srv = $( "input:radio[name=server]:checked" ).val();
  $.ajax
  ({
      cache: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "playercard.php",
      data: "name=" + name + "&server=" + srv,
      success: function (msg)
      {      
              $("#contentarea").html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

playercard.php (main content):

```
$( document ).on('click', '#refreshbutton', function() {
  $.ajax
  ({
      cache: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "playercard.php",
      data: "name=<?php echo $summoner; ?>&server=<?php echo $server;     ?>",
      success: function (msg)
      {      
              $("#contentarea").html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Everything works fine on the first search. (type in search, submit, content area gets populated with data from playercard.php) The refresh button on playercard.php also works fine.

But, if I make another search, the content area does get populated with new content. But when I click the refresh button, it reloads the data from the first search. (Even though caching is disabled and the get parameters seem to be right.)

Any idea of what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;)

This line is causing this unexpected behavior:

```
data: "name=<?php echo $summoner; ?>&server=<?php echo $server;     ?>",
```

Here you are setting values using `PHP` which are always same for each request you need to replace these values with JavaScript values same as you are doing in `searchbar.php`; So replace `playercard.php` with the following code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#refreshbutton', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = encodeURIComponent($( "#name" ).val());
  var srv = $( "input:radio[name=server]:checked" ).val();
  $.ajax({
      cache: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "playercard.php",
      data: "name=" + name + "&server=" + srv,
      success: function(msg)
      {
        $("#contentarea").html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
      }
    });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: That worked. However, it requires the content of the form to stay the same. In other words, it's effectively the same as resubmitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would suggest is to add a random number to your data.
So the data part would be:

```
data: "name=" + name + "&server=" + srv +"&random="+Math.random(),
```

In this way, the `url+data` is always different. 
Sometimes the `url` is cached and it always returns the same values for the same data.

On the other hand, I would try to avoid using  `event.preventDefault();`, returning false, it is enough.